# How to programmatically create/populate view respecting MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

In my WPF application I have a MainView composed of three Views (custom UserControls). The layout of my views are done (in XAML) but now I have to read a configuration file and populate my views. When I read the configuration file, the model objects should be created as well as the view items.

The more complex view (lets call it View1) will have tabs comprising a set of buttons separated by categories (arranged in StackPanels+GroupBox).

Since the main components of the view are buttons that will trigger actions of my model, my question is: how to achieve this using MVVM?

Will the ViewModel be responsible for creating it's view? If not, how would it use commands?

P.S. I'm using MVVM Light Toolkit

Answer (score 3):

No, the ViewModel is not responsible for creating its view. Generally people use XAML DataTemplates to map a ViewModel object to a UserControl. This is known as "ViewModel first".
You can also create the views yourself, and inject the ViewModels manually. This is known as "View first". Generally ViewModel first seems more popular.

I'm not sure what your issue is with the buttons. You simply expose RelayCommands in your ViewModel, and you bind your buttons to them in the view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I may be over-thinking it. I'm new to wpf and it's tricky to deal with it without knowing what is going to be in my view, how many buttons and what kind of buttons.. I'll try to dive into the code and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky to get the hang of. Try and think about commands on a ViewModel rather than buttons on a view. It's the ViewModel where all the guts are. The view is just a thin "skin" that sits on top.